# Visual Studio 2010 hangs when opening websites

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, freeze

My Visual Studio 2010 Professional hangs up 99.999% of the time when I try to open a website as "Remote Site" through an HTTP address. However if i open the site through a unc path instead of through HTTP, it works fine. Of course that is not always feasible, for example when working from offsite. The same sites (assuming they are not NET40 sites) work fine in Visual Studio 2008, so I'm pretty sure it is not a problem with the Front Page Server Extensions.

If i run 2010 in `/safe` mode, it opens the projects fine. So i figured maybe it was one of my installed extensions. I therefore disabled all my extensions and tried again, but it still hangs up. So it is apparently something in Visual Studio itself that is different between safe and normal modes.

I ran it in logging mode, and checked the log but did not see anything that stuck out to me. The log is uploaded here: http://pastebin.com/aUnVanB1 .

The exact symptoms I am seeing are that when i click on the project name, it pops up and asks me for my credentials. I enter those, and click OK, and it then loads the solution explorer, and i see the tree view, but then it just hangs with the progress dialog that says `"Preparing Solution..."`. The progress bar keeps cycling, but it never finishes loading, and the spot where the properties window would be in the VS UI is completely unpainted, with just a blank, empty, white space.

Any one have any clue what else i could do to try to figure out why 2010 hangs when attempting to load websites via HTTP? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your question... you gave me the right clue to solve my problem!

My VS 2010 was hanging (in fact was very slow to get available) when I was openening a solution containing a remote website and I was due to press Escape a few times to cancel the pending operation... As you suggest I tried to open such a solution with /safeMode and VS2010 became available quite instantly.

So as you pointed the VS Extensions... I checked mine (all from Telerik): opening the extension manager I discovered that some updates where available. I thought the extensions updates were automatically proposed and so never checked that before. In fact, you need to manually check with the extension manager if some are available.

I've updated all my Telerik extensions... and now I may open normally all solutions including a remote website.

Thanks a lot! Perhaps... you need to updates your extensions???

Comment: Thanks for that! Turns out my situation was similar. Though my VS was always telling me `this extension has an update` or `that extension has an update`, so since it seemed to be working, I didn't question it. I went and looked and sure enough, the **Telerik VS Extensions** extension had an update, which VS had never told me about. I updated that, and have now closed and reopened VS several times, and it seems to work every time. Odd. Thanks though!

Comment: Had the same issue, but opening local web sites. Deleted all my Extensions in Extension Manger and it went away, trying to determine which one caused it. MY best guess is Productivity Power Tools, though it might be a combination of that an another extension. but I remove PPT and it goes away, put PPT back and it returns

Answer (score 1):

Check you network order preference in Windows.

I had a similar problem where DNS would cause a hang of 1 minute before trying again (and again and finally on the next network).

Under Network, Advanced Settings (WinXP):
[image]